# Android - Request passcode before disabling device admin

Tags: android

I'm wanting to make an applock app where users can password protect apps. I will be using device administrator however if a malicious user where to access the phone whilst unlocked, he could disable it from the settings and easily uninstall.

A popular app called 'applock' has an advanced protection app that allows them to request a password before disabling device administrator.

How could I offer this functionality? I want to use the phones existing passcode.

Answer (score 0):

In your DeviceAdminReceiver class, override this method:

```
public CharSequence onDisableRequested(Context context, Intent intent);
```

Here you should be able to lock the device immediately (since you will still have admin privileges).  Once the user unlocks the device, they will be able to hit the ok button  to deactivate your app.  This would look something like this:

```
@Override
public CharSequence onDisableRequested(Context context, Intent intent) {
    DevicePolicyManager dpm = (DevicePolicyManager)
    context.getApplicationContext().getSystemService(Context.DEVICE_POLICY_SERVICE);
    dpm.lockNow();
    Log.d(TAG, "Disable requested");
    return "Are you sure??"; //This gets displayed in an alert dialog, but will only be visible after the user unlocks the screen
}
```

I realize this isn't exactly what you're asking, but the end result is similar.  The alternate solution I've seen reference elsewhere is to implement a Service with listens for running applications/Activities (like AppBlock does).  If it sees that the Activity to disable device administrator is running, it pops up a new Activity to request a password.

I suspect that would work, but I haven't coded it myself.  Additionally, I'm not sure how you would have that Activity request the device password as opposed to some internal password for your app.

Hope that helps!